# How can i solve this; Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to mask for phone number. I tried to use Ajax Control Tool Kit - MaskedEditExtender for this. I downloaded Ajax Control Tool Kit from Nuget. On the Aspx page, I added the code I found on the internet, where the error was given below. But I don't know how to solve this error. Can you help me?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so say we want to autocomplete a text box (against say the database).

so, we would first do a nuget of ajaxtoolkit.

Then, we drop a text box on a form.

We should see this - say this markup:

Then we now click on the text box in the designer.

[image]

And then

[image]

so, now our markup is this:

```
        <h3>enter hotel Name</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtHotel_AutoCompleteExtender"
            runat="server" BehaviorID="txtHotel_AutoCompleteExtender" DelimiterCharacters="" 
            TargetControlID="txtHotel"
            ServiceMethod = "SearchCustomers"
            MinimumPrefixLength = "1" 
            CompletionInterval="100" 
            EnableCaching="false" 
            CompletionSetCount="10" >
       </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Note that I displayed the property sheet, and filled out the above values.
(remove the ServicePath="" - you don't need it).

so, now our code behind:

```
    // using System.Web.Services;

    [WebMethod()]
    public static List<string> SearchCustomers(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        
        List<string> customers = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL 
                = "select HotelName FROM tblHotels WHERE HotelName like @SearchText + '%' ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchText", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = prefixText;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                        customers.Add(sdr["HotelName"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return customers;
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

So, you create a web method in the code behind.

## Edit: you wanted a mask

Somehow, I posted the wrong info and answer for this quesiton.

However, for a edit mask?

Then again, drop in a text box, extender - edit mask.

So, say this:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">

        </asp:TextBox>
```

and then:

[image]

We now have this for the markup:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>

        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender"
            runat="server" BehaviorID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender"
            TargetControlID="TextBox1" Mask="(999)-999-9999" />
```

Doing above, should insert (add) to the page at the top this:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

And now when we enter that textbox, you get this:

[image]